# Aura components super badge Step 10 Error - The Map component isn't available in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, superbadges

I was just about to finish this super badge when I encountered this error. I have updated the map component(which comes in unmanaged packaged that you install for this) as per the requirement and placed it on to the page using lightning app builder and the component is even showing up on the page but for some reason the platform keeps throwing me this error below. I tried many different things, I even deleted the whole Map bundle and created a new one and placed it on the page but the same error keeps popping. I have run out of ideas and really frustrated now. Any help is greatly appreciated :(

P.S Hoping its not because of some silly mistake 
[image: Map component isn't available in app builder]

Answer (score 1):

It was a technical error at the back end. I raised a ticket to salesforce help and they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
```

Make the component flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes and global access will fix this issue.